# Google Drive API - List Permissions of a file

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am using the list permissions endpoint (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) to get all the permissions for a file that exists in a shared drive.

I am running into an issue with a file I have that lives in a shared drive. The file has 100 permissions. The max limit on the number of permissions returned for a shared drive file is 100, so I should only need to make one request to get all the permissions for the file and the API should not return a next page token.

But this is not the behaviour I am experiencing, after the first request I continuously get the same next page token back from the API.

So for the following code below (written in go), I get into an infinite loop, since I continuously get the same next page token back.

```golang
var permissionService PermissionsService := getPermissionsService()

fileID := "1234abcd"
nextPageToken := ""
anotherPage := true
permissions := []*Permission{}
for anotherPage {
    result, err := permissionService.
        List(fileID).
        SupportsAllDrives(true).
        SupportsTeamDrives(false).
        Fields("*").
        PageSize(100).
        Do()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    anotherPage = result.NextPageToken != ""
    nextPageToken = result.NextPageToken
    permissions = append(permissions, result.Permissions...)
}

fmt.Println("Permissions", permissions)
```

Am I supposed to account for this case in my code? From the documentation, this is never mentioned so I assume this is not supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you did not add the `PageToken` parameter in your `permissionService`. You are actually requesting the same first 100 results of the permission service.

Not familiar with the language but something like this

```
for anotherPage {
    result, err := permissionService.
        List(fileID).
        SupportsAllDrives(true).
        SupportsTeamDrives(false).
        Fields("*").
        PageSize(100).
        PageToken(nextPageToken).
        Do()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    anotherPage = result.NextPageToken != ""
    nextPageToken = result.NextPageToken
    permissions = append(permissions, result.Permissions...)
}
```

Can you also verify first if the `result.NextPageToken` will return "" if the file has < 100 results, I used API explorer and Apps Script to access this API and the `nextPageToken` is not part of the response body when permission list is less than the `pageSize`.